# Is this paint lead based?

Tags: uk, paint-removal, protection, lead

In my cellar there’s a thin layer of crumbling paint directly on brick.

I am concerned that it might be lead based, and I need a better mask than a cheap dust mask. The house is old, Victorian (early 1900s by my estimate). The paint is slightly grey/green in some places, and whiter in others.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't tell by looks - [get a lead testing kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008BK15PU).

If you knew for sure that the paint was 100 years old that would significantly increase the chances of it being lead-based. But it could be that the wall was originally bare brick and painted relatively recently.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably grab one. This is the UK page for any future readers: https://amzn.to/2PFogGS.

Comment: Agreed you can't tell by looking & test kits are cheap.+ anything Pryor to the 60's is probably lead based as that was the standard for long lasting paint back then, however it could be white wash I can't tell from the photo

Comment: Rather than spend the money on a test kit I decided to just buy the correct mask (FFP3) and some gloves. It was pretty much the same price anyway.